# Probe csv content type and unit test in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, csv

Why the following line of Java code

```
 Objects.equals(Files.probeContentType(file.toPath()), "text/csv")
```

always returns `true` if `file` has csv extension but non-csv content?

Maybe, the csv content is any text?

How can I define a file with csv extension but non-csv content to do a proper unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV format is not defined without additional information as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Additional information could be the expected delimiter, number of fields on a line, charset etc. Then you can check if a file content meets your expectations by implementing a custom logic to check it.